# how to parse a List of Objects in a json file and display it?

Tags: json, angular, angular8

I'm trying to use the import method to parse a json file, this is what my code looks like.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as data from './cities.json';


@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'weather-app';

  cities: any = (data as any).default;

constructor(){}
 ngOnInit(){
console.log(data);
 }
}
```

and this is how i'm trying to display it,

```
<ul *ngFor="let c of cities"> 
<li>{{c.CityName}}</li>    
</ul>
```

My console log displays everything but it does not appear in the angular app list, What am i doing wrong here? I'll post the json file i'm trying to parse below. thanks in advance :)

```
 {"List":
 [{"CityCode":"1248991","CityName":"Colombo","Temp":"33.0","Status":"Clouds"}, 
  {"CityCode":"1850147","CityName":"Tokyo","Temp":"8.6","Status":"Clear"}, 
  {"CityCode":"2644210","CityName":"Liverpool","Temp":"16.5","Status":"Rain"}, 
  {"CityCode":"2988507","CityName":"Paris","Temp":"22.4","Status":"Clear"}, 
  {"CityCode":"2147714","CityName":"Sydney","Temp":"27.3","Status":"Rain"}, 
  {"CityCode":"4930956","CityName":"Boston","Temp":"4.2","Status":"Mist"}, 
  {"CityCode":"1796236","CityName":"Shanghai","Temp":"10.1","Status":"Clouds"}, 
  {"CityCode":"3143244","CityName":"Oslo","Temp":"-3.9","Status":"Clear"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your root object is not of type Array, your object is

```
{ 
  List: city[]
}
```

You may access the property `List`

```
<ul *ngFor="let c of cities.List"> 
<li>{{c.CityName}}</li>    
</ul>
```

Note: that your code needs refactoring as it does not appear as clean code. my answer is just to show to you where is the mistake

Comment: Thankyou! Yes i know it's not clean i just wrote it to see if the data gets parsed properly :)